# Multiple unions in Spark - how does Spark generate the plan

Tags: apache-spark, union, operator-keyword, execution, sql-execution-plan

I have multiple unions in a sequence across different RDDs as shown below:

```
val result = rdd1 union rdd2 union rdd3 union rdd4
```

Will Spark generate the unions serially (which is O(n)), or will Spark generate a plan which is parallel (O(log(n))? I.e. will it do `rdd1 union rdd2` in parallel to `rdd3 union rdd4` and then union the results of these two?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rdd1.union(rdd2)` to take the union of two RDDs. In this case a new `UnionRDD` is created for every pair of RDDs joined. Alternatively you can use `sc.union(Seq(rdd1, rdd2))` for taking the union of more than two RDDs at the same time. In this case only a single `UnionRDD` is created no matter how many RDDs are combined.

A union of RDDs is very simple: it just puts the partitions of one RDD after the partitions of the other. Because the actual computations happen on the partitions, the run time of operating on a union of RDDs is the same as the time it would take to operate on the RDDs without a union. Therefore the cost of the union can generally be ignored.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that `rdd1.union(rdd2)` does not trigger any computation. RDD transformations are lazy. They only affect how computations will unfold when they are eventually triggered by a computation. Another thing is that partitions are always processed in parallel, one per executor core. So you take the union of 100 RDDs with 1 partitions each (using whichever method) if you have 100 cores the result will be all tasks processed in parallel. Neither O(n) nor O(log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

Visualizing union:
if you had 4 RDDs each made of 4 partitions

[image: RDDs partitions split on several cores]

after **`.union`** you would have one RDD made of 16 partitions

[image]

No shuffling is performed in a `union`. It's just a bookkeeping change. It's extremely efficient. It must be used whenever possible (for example instead of `OR` in a `join` criteria).